# How to combine key and value using Jackson (Spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

I have json like below.

```json
{
  "USER0001": {
    "name": "hoge",
    "age": 20
  },
  "USER0002": {
    "name": "huga",
    "age": 10
  }
}
```

and, this is my `User` data class.

```kotlin
data class User(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
)
```

then, I want to convert json to user list when request is send controller.

```kotlin
listOf(
    User("USER0001", "hoge", 20),
    User("USER0002", "huga", 10),
)
```

and my controller .

```kotlin
@RestController
class MyController() {
    fun test(@RequestBody users: List<User>) {
        // some code. I want to use users as List<User>
    }

}
```

I try using `@JsonComponent` like below,

```kotlin
    class Deserializer : JsonDeserializer<List<User>>() {
        override fun deserialize(parser: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): List<User> {

            val treeNode = parser.codec.readTree<TreeNode>(parser)

            val fieldNames = treeNode.fieldNames()

            val result = mutableListOf<User>()

            while(fieldNames.hasNext()) {
                val fieldName = fieldNames.next()
                val userJson = treeNode.get(fieldName)
                // I can't use this code as String type.
                val name = userJson.get("name")


                // How Can I make User model ???

            }

            return result
        }
    }
```

then, I don't know how to make `User` object in `deserializer` method.

do you know how to do this ?

thank you reading.

Comment: Instead of trying to manipulate the JSON, what do you think about first parsing the provided JSON as-is into a `Map<String, UserDetails>`, and then in plain Kotlin code you can convert the map to the list of `User`s?

Comment: @aSemy Thanks!! That's the simplest way. I was overthinking it.... Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

this is simple way.

```kotlin
@RestController
class MyController() {
    fun test(@RequestBody Map<String, UserDetail>) {
        // some code...
    }
}
```